# Why does set-builder notation have this particular property?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, notation

Consider $\{z\in \mathbb{Z} : z = ax + by\;\exists\, x, y \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ and $\{ax + by : \forall\, x, y \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. These two sets are one and the same. But noticed that the quantifiers flipped. Why does this happen?

Comment: The second notation is just wrong.

Comment: Neither expression makes a lot of sense as written, they'd usually be written as $\{z\in\Bbb Z\colon\exists x,y\in\Bbb Z(z=ax+by)\}$ and $\{ax+by\colon x,y\in\Bbb Z\}$

Comment: Your notations are sloppy and @AlessandroCodenotti has the proper ones. Let him write it as an answer and we can all move on, I say.

Answer (score 2):

Let a,b be integers.
The correct set construction is
{ ax + by : x,y in Z }.

Comment: $x, y$ are bound (not free) variables. In the classical predicate logic on which standard mathematics is founded, every bound variable must have exactly one of these two scopes: $\exists$ or $\forall$. Which are the scopes for $x, y$?

Comment: @BalancedTryteOperators The set-builder notation *itself* incorporates a kind of variable-binding - namely, in the bit following the colon. What William Elliot has written is correct. You can switch between set-builder notation and formulas as follows: the set $\{ax+by: x,y\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ is the unique set $S$ such that $\forall s[s\in S\iff \exists x,y\in\mathbb{Z}(s=ax+by)].$

Comment: You may also find it clearer to write $$\{z: \exists x,y\in\mathbb{Z}(z=ax+by)\}.$$ This would also be correct, and avoids the implicit variable-binding issue in what William Elliot has written. However, what he's written is in fact in keeping with standard convention.

Answer (score 1):

Neither of your proposals is correct. The first one, however, comes close to an expression which *is* valid: $$\{z\in\mathbb{Z}: \exists x,y\in\mathbb{Z}(z=ax+by)\}.$$ However, you'll commonly - more commonly perhaps - find expressions like $$\{ax+by: x,y\in\mathbb{Z}\}.$$ These expressions are a bit syntactically weird: there's an implicit variable binding going on after the colon. Intuitively, when we introduce some new variables to the left of the colon and then include constraints on those variables to the right of the colon, those variables range over all objects satisfying those constraints.

A bit more snappily: given a term $t(x_1,...,x_n)$, the expression $$\{t(x_1,...,x_n): [stuff]\}$$ is accepted notation for the set $$\{y: \exists x_1,...,x_n([stuff]\mbox{ and }y=t(x_1,...,x_n)\}.$$

Comment: but in the second set it looks like $x, y$ are ranging over all of the universe of discourse. Semantically speaking that would make their scope $\forall$.

Comment: @BalancedTryteOperators It shouldn't - the requirement "$x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$" indicates that they range over $\mathbb{Z}$ alone. Since set-builder notation builds a *term* as opposed to a *formula*, it doesn't behave entirely like $\forall$/$\exists$.

Comment: 1. Yes SBN builds a term but the variables bound **are** predicate variables because the set being constructed is second-order term while the bound-variables are first-order. 2. If it looks like a duck, walks like a duck, swims like a duck, flies like a duck, and quacks like a duck, it's a duck. $x, y$ are bound variables that take on every possible value in the universe of discourse. What else does that make them?

Comment: @BalancedTryteOperators I don't really understand what you're getting at at this point. Notation like "$\{ax+by: x,y\in\mathbb{Z}\}$" is by convention accepted as shorthand for "$\{z: \exists x,y\in\mathbb{Z}(z=ax+by)\}$." You may object to that shorthand, but it's a piece of accepted syntax which is being used consistently here.

Comment: Meanwhile, your first/second order distinction on the variables is a bit off - in theories like ZFC, *everything* is a set, so that's not actually a fundamental point here.

Comment: ZFC *encodes* first, second, etc... order predicates as sets and works only in FOL. But that is just an *encoding*. In the actual mental logic that mathematicians think in they're not the same.